# Grid System in bootstrap MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

I get some issues in the grid system.

I design this label and text box but I want all this together. 
 How can I do that ? 
 I tried but it is not come with me

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXCxJ.png)

This is my code:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-12" })
        <div class="col-md-10" >
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control " } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe `col-md-12` should be replaced by `col-md-2` is order to not exceed 12 columns. 
Also, adding a `row` class with your `form-group`, and `col-form-label` in place of `control-label` if you are using bootstrap 4.

```
<div class="form-group row">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-md-2 col-form-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10" >
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control " } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    </div>
</div>
```

Please consult the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/) for more details.

Comment: Thank you but it is not come , because my dir="rtl"